# How to make all conditions (if, elif, else) work, in for loop, with try except in Python

Tags: python, for-loop, if-statement, try-catch, except

We have a list of dictionaries.

On users input we have 4 possible results:

1. Account inserted correctly -> show all info.
2. If the length of the input is not equal to 5 (all accounts are consists of 5 digits) -> stop the program with output f"There are 5 digits in the account, you inserted {len(acc)}".
3. If the input is not an integer -> stop the program with output "There are no letters in the account! Please insert 5 digits".
4. If the input is an integer, the length is 5 digits, but there is no account like that in our list of dictionaries -> stop the program with output f" Sorry, Could not find {acc}!"

Please, see code below:

```
test_dict = [{"account_number": 12345, "Name" : "Nick"},
             {"account_number": 76531, "Name" : "Carl"},
             {"account_number": 75321, "Name" : "Mary"}]

acc = input("Insert Account Number: ")

try:
    for i in test_dict:
        try:
            if int(acc) == i["account_number"]:
                print(i)
            elif len(acc) != 5:
                print(f"There are 5 digits in the account, you inserted {len(acc)}")
                break
        except:
            print("There are no letters in the account! Please insert 5 digits")
            break
except:
    print(f"Sorry, Could not find {acc}!")
```

My goal is to make sure all conditions work.

So far I was able to make the first 3 conditions work, but I stuck at the final one - **If the input is an integer, the length is 5 digits, but there is no account like that in our list of dictionaries -> stop the program with output f" Sorry, Could not find {acc}!"**

It doesn't raise any error, there is just no output, like an empty string or something like that.

Hope you can help me.

Comment: *"Good Afternoon."* You have to think more globally.

Answer (score 1):

Seems you were nearly there, just had some additional elements that were unnecessary.

The exterior `try` loop seems like it can be omitted, thus your final condition can simply be an `else` condition.

Also included a `break` following the first `if` statement to avoid having both the `if` statement and `else` statement produce simultaneous outputs.

See if this works out for you!

```
test_dict = [{"account_number": 12345, "Name" : "Nick"},
             {"account_number": 76531, "Name" : "Carl"},
             {"account_number": 75321, "Name" : "Mary"}]

acc = input("Insert Account Number: ")


for i in test_dict:
    try:
        if int(acc) == i["account_number"]:
            print(i)
            break
        elif len(acc) != 5:
            print(f"There are 5 digits in the account, you inserted {len(acc)}")
            break
    except:
        print("There are no letters in the account! Please insert 5 digits")
        break
else:
    print(f"Sorry, Could not find {acc}!")
```

Answer (score 0):

You almost got it. Good work.

The except clause only gets run if there is an error. Your code doesn't work because the last except does not get run if there are no errors.

Read about try-except here for more info:
https://realpython.com/python-exceptions/

Below is another approach for you to consider.
The approach tries to catch as many errors it can as quickly as possible and only then works on the test_dict. The benefit of this is that it will execute quickly for a test_dict with a few 1000 accounts. Validation first, processing last.

```
test_dict = [{"account_number": 12345, "Name" : "Nick"},
             {"account_number": 76531, "Name" : "Carl"},
             {"account_number": 75321, "Name" : "Mary"}]

account = input("Insert Account Number: ")

match_found = False
try:
    account = int(account)
except:
    print("Invalid characters entered for the account. Please enter numbers only.")
else:
    if len(str(account)) != 5:
        print(f"There are 5 digits in the account, you inserted {len(str(account))}")
    else:
        for i in test_dict:
            if i["account_number"] == account:
                print(i)
                match_found = True
                break
        if not match_found:
            print(f"Sorry, Could not find {account}!")
```